# Add new column to existing table Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a table input and I need to add the calculation to it i.e. add a new column. I have tried:

1. to do the calculation and then, feed back. Obviously, it stuck the new data to the old data.
2. to do the calculation and then feed back but truncate the table. As the process got stuck at some point, I assume what happens is that I was truncating the table while the data was still getting extracted from it.
3. to use stream lookup and then, feed back. Of course, it also stuck the data on the top of the existing data.
4. to use stream lookup where I pull the data from the table input, do the calculation, at the same time, pull the data from the same table and do a lookup based on the unique combination of date and id. And use the 'Update' step.

As it is has been running for a while, I am positive it is not the option but I exhausted my options.

Comment: please explain the issue properly.

Comment: @WorkingHard..I am not sure what else I can add...I have a table input and I need to add one additional column to it 2with the value from which come from the calculator step. The problem is that I don't understand what step I should use to feed the values back to the original input table.

Comment: You mean that you have table input where two Columns are present let's say A,B then you are using calculator and generating third column C and you want to 3 columns in result A,B,C .. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. Sorry, now I see what you mean by improper explanation.

Comment: actully once you connect the hope, result of 1st step is automatically carried forward to the next step.
so let's say you have table input step and then you add calculator where you are creating 3rd column. after writing logic right click on calculator step and click on preview you will get the result with all 3 columns.

Comment: Yes, but then, how do I save it in the database, the original table? What step should I use?

Comment: i don't understand your use-case, why you want to store something in original table,create one more table as a result table and use that table for your further processing.

Comment: Is it how it is supposed to be? I am using this table for my dashboards. I really doubt if it is the way, with all due respect. Because it means whenever I add a new col, I am creating new and new table.

Comment: yes. so basic behaviour is take the data from source do the necessary changes on that data(what we call it as a transforming the data) and load the result into destination, so in your case save the result in some other table and refer that table for creating dashboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193550/discussion-between-working-hard-and-eponkratova).

Comment: Yeah, it is just I already have all the transformation done previously and loaded historicals but I realized I need one more column. OK, another column is another column! Thank u!

Comment: @WorkingHard.., I don't see how I can accept your answer as the solution!

Comment: i added the comment in answer, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that you need to update the table where your data came from with this new field. Use the Update step with fields A and B as keys.

Comment: Is it my option 4 from the list? If yes, I got just a new dataset appended to my old datasest

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to do the lookup, just use the Update step passing fields A and B as keys.

Answer (score 0):

actully once you connect the hope, result of 1st step is automatically carried forward to the next step. so let's say you have table input step and then you add calculator where you are creating 3rd column. after writing logic right click on calculator step and click on preview you will get the result with all 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your issue is not ONLY in Pentaho implementation, there are somethings you can do before reaching Data Staging in Pentaho.

1. 'Workin Hard' is correct when he says you shouldn't use the same table, but instead leave the input untouched, and just upload / insert the new values into a new table, doesn't have to be a new table EVERYTIME, but instead of truncating the original, you truncate the staging table (output table).
2. How many 'new columns' will you need ? Will every iteration of this run create a new column in the output ? Or you will always have a 'C' Column which is always A+B or some other calculation ? I'm sorry but this isn't clear. If the case is the later, you don't need Pentaho for transformations, Updating 'C' Column with a math or function considering A+B, this can be done directly in most relational DBMS with a simple UPDATE clause. Yes, it can be done in Pentaho, but you're putting a lot of overhead and processing time.

Comment: Hi @Cristian, the idea is to generate this column in the existing dataset; and then, just update it every day as a part of my ETL

Comment: Hi @eponkratova, then i guess your best bet is what working hard stated (i think) create a C column in the table, and update it. Depending on how you build this table with unique keys, you don't need a Stream Lookup, would you mind sharing said table with us in your question so that we can better help you out with your KTR ?